# Enum with Parameters to Scala 3 Causes Serialization Errors

Tags: scala, scala-3

Consider the following code:

```scala
enum BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(val value: Long):
  case Inclusion          extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 0)
  case Exclusion          extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 1)
  case Exception          extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 2)

@main def main(): Unit = {
  println(BrandSafetyFeatureStatus.values)
}
```

Which works great.
My question is why if I add new `case` with parameters or just with `()`:

```scala
enum BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(val value: Long):
  case Inclusion          extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 0)
  case Exclusion          extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 1)
  case Exception          extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 2)
  private case Mixed(mixed: Long) extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(mixed) // ⚠️

  // Add Bitwise
  def |(other: BrandSafetyFeatureStatus): BrandSafetyFeatureStatus = Mixed(value | other.value)
  def hasFlag(flag: BrandSafetyFeatureStatus): Boolean = (value & flag.value) == flag.value

@main def main(): Unit = {
  println(BrandSafetyFeatureStatus.valueOf("X")) // Not compiles
  println(BrandSafetyFeatureStatus.values) // Not compiles
}
```

The serialization function of `values` and `valueOf` generate me an error of:

```
value values is not a member of object scala3.BrandSafetyFeatureStatus. Although class BrandSafetyFeatureStatus is an enum, it has non-singleton cases, meaning a values array is not defined
```

**Is it by design? is it an open bug?**
I know that with `enumeratum` I can solve it as follows:

```scala
sealed class BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(val value: Long) extends EnumEntry {
  def | (other: BrandSafetyFeatureStatus): BrandSafetyFeatureStatus = BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(value | other.value)
  def hasFlag(flag: BrandSafetyFeatureStatus): Boolean = (value & flag.value) == flag.value
}

object BrandSafetyFeatureStatus extends Enum[BrandSafetyFeatureStatus]:
  case object Inclusion         extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 1)
  case object Exclusion         extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 2)
  case object Exception         extends BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(1L << 3)

  override def values: IndexedSeq[BrandSafetyFeatureStatus] = findValues

@main def main(): Unit = {
  println(BrandSafetyFeatureStatus.withName("X"))
  println(BrandSafetyFeatureStatus.values)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a parameterless case like this:

```
enum Foo:
  case Bar
  case Baz
```

The fact that these `case`es are parameterless means that you can create the set of all possible values:

```
val values = Set(Foo.Bar, Foo.Baz)
```

When you define

```
enum Foo:
  case Bar
  case Baz
  case Third(something: Int)
```

How could you define `values` upfront? Well, you cannot. Enumeratum is a library which creates such set of `values` and use it to provide some functionalities:

- convert between reference (there is only 1 instance of each value) and some string with its name
- convert between reference and its ordinal
- etc

It achieves it by finding all subtypes of enum, verifying that each of them in a singleton with only 1 value, putting these values into `values` (all of that so far with `findValues` macro, and you putting this macro after `val values =` ), and finally taking that `values` list and iterating over it to produce `String`s and `Int`s with some helper function.

This cannot be done if any of the `case`es is not a value. Even empty parameter list (e.g. `case Value()`) would mean that when you do `Value()` you are calling a constructor, creating a new instance, with a new reference, and the mechanism above is not accessible anymore. `findValues` for `enum` with parameters will just fail in compilation.

Serialization of parameterless values is trivial, because there is always an easy way to translate each value to some string - namely the value assigned by Enumeratum as the name (it can be customized).

What when you need to parse it somehow? (To figure what values pass into these parameters). Well, then there is no single, generic behavior, that could be assumed to always be safe to use. In such case you'd have to read how your particular library handles (de)serialization of ADTs: does it use discrimination field, or some fallback behavior, or something else. (Enumeratun *on its own* is *not* a serialization library, but it has integrations with some of them).

So it's by design.